# intercambiar imagen en listview personalizado Android Studio

Tags: android, listview

estoy obteniendo los datos de sqlite de la siguiente forma.

```
public Cursor informacionPrincipal() {
    String whereClause = "estado = ?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] {"1"};

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_REGISTRO, new String[]{
            COLUMN_ID,
            COLUMN_REGISTRO,
            COLUMN_HUERTO,
            COLUMN_UBICACION
     }, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

y muestro la información en el `Listview` de la siguiente manera:

```
public void MostrarListado() {
    try {
        Cursor cursor = basededatos.informacionPrincipal();
        if (cursor == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Se ha presentado un problema al cargar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ninguna Corte", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        String[] columns = new String[]{
                basededatos.COLUMN_ID,
                basededatos.COLUMN_REGISTRO,
                basededatos.COLUMN_HUERTO,
                basededatos.COLUMN_UBICACION
        };

        int[] boundTo = new int[]{
                R.id.txtCodigo_Listado,
                R.id.txtCreacion_Listado,
                R.id.txtHuerto_Cancelado,
                R.id.txtUbicacion_Listado
        };

        simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.item_listado,
                cursor,
                columns,
                boundTo,
                0);

        listado.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Se ha producido un error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

quiero que si `COLUMN_REGISTRO es igual a 20` por ejemplo me muestre una imagen que tengo ya en el folder `minimap`. y `si es 10 me muestre otra` pero donde debería ir la condicion?

Comment: Has hecho algo del ListView? ¿Algún adapter? Si es así, por favor agrega tu código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con un [`SimpleCursorAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) no es posible, tienes que implementar un CustomAdapter que extienda de  `SimpleCursorAdapter` y dentro de `bindView()`, realizarías la validación.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

...
...
...

@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {

  int columnRegistro = c.getColumnIndex("column_registro");     
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.myimageview);

    if (columnRegistro == 20) {
      //carga imagen de /mipmap.
      imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.mi_imagen);
    }else if (columnRegistro == 10) {
      //carga otra imagen...
  imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.otra_imagen);
    } 

 }

...
...


}
```

---

Agrego un ejemplo de **CustomAdapter** :

```
  public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

            private Context mContext;
            private Context appContext;
            private int layout;
            private Cursor c;
            private final LayoutInflater inflater;

            public CustomAdapter(Context context,int layout, Cursor c,String[] from,int[] to) {
                super(context, layout, c, from, to);
                this.layout = layout;
                this.mContext = context;
                this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                this.c = c;
            }

            @Override
            public View newView (Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                    return inflater.inflate(layout, null);
            }

            @Override
            public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
                ...
                ...
                ...

            }

    }
```

Comment: Toda la razon no me fije bien que no ocupa adapter!

Comment: soy nuevo en esto de android, apenas lo estoy manejando, ¿donde deberia ir esta pedazo de codigo que me has aportado? ¿dentro de donde?

Comment: SimpleCursorAdapter es un adapter limitado debes crear una clase aparte y en lugar de  new SimpleCursorAdapter() definirias esta clase, permiteme buscar un ejemplo.

Comment: @PepinoMorales Listo pepino agrega esa clase.

Comment: Muchas gracias lo probare

Comment: `customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,R.layout.item_listado,cursor,columns,boundTo);
            listado.setAdapter(customAdapter);`

No me muestra la informacion, solo recorre al parecer el contaro me muestra 4 filas que son las que tengo pero no muestra la informacion de cada una ni carga la imagen.